# Login page keeps showing error PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am having issues getting some simple (or it seems simple) coding to cooperate. I've tried stripping it completely and typing everything out. Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(trim($_POST['password']));
    include('includes/admin.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo '<p>Incorrect login.<br><a href="adminlogin.php">Return to Login Page</a></p>';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
        echo '<p>Login successful.<br><a href="admin.php">Go to Admin Page</a></p>';
    }
}
?>
```

The goal is to have it redirect to the login page if unsuccessful and to redirect to another admin page if successful. I keep getting the "Incorrect Login" error, even when I type in the correct username and password.

Side Note: I know to redirect, I need to use `header('Location: link.php')`, it is not included for testing purposes.

Comment: check echo `$sql` query it gets corrects result or not.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";

Comment: please echo $sql and try to run directly then you can get query is correct or not

Comment: Tried the echo $sql and it is not showing the correct password information but something completely random.

Comment: I took off md5 and the echo $sql returned the correct information but I am still getting the incorrect error when I try to put in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't save your password as MD5 hash in your database you will never match it, cause in the line above you hash the password via MD5 before using in the query.

1. MD5 isn't secure! Use the PHP internal functions (password_hash(), password_verify()) to create and check passwords!
2. Use prepared statements!

Example code:

```php
<?php

// Save a new user password in DB
$username = 'Max User';
$password = 'My_Secr3t_Pa5sw0rd';
$passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`) VALUES(?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $passwordHash);
$stmt->execute();

// Check user password
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if (password_verify($password, $row['password']) {
    echo "Password correct";
} else {
    echo "Password incorrect!";
}

?>
```

Comment: What exactly have you done? Hopefully not just copy&paste this example code.
How does you current code look?